# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't show menu toolbar and launcher

Tags: apt, unity, compiz, ccsm

When I was trying to run my Ubuntu and I logged in to my Ubuntu I saw that it doesn't show menu toolbar and I just saw my desktop and nothing else!

I googled it and I understood that I have to install ccsm but when I try to run in my terminal

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

it said me:

```
Unmet dependencies try apt-get -f install...
```

I tried that also but I got that same message from terminal again!
What should I do?

Comment: can you help on this problem?@v010dya

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I've tried to clear up this question by editing a  bit.  Please feel free to re-edit it if I have changed your intent anywhere.

Comment: And as a side note, it would  be much better if you could copy the *exact* message from the terminal and [edit] it into your question; it leaves less room for guessing.

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`?  When you have run both of those try running `sudo apt -f install` again.  It could be that there's just some repo or package that's outdated causing broken dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for edit! yes i tried to update but not upgrade. I will try that too and i hope that will work..@anonymous2